# Hibernate does not work with Ubuntu and Kali Linux dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, partition, kali-linux, swap, hibernate

After reading up and doing some research I found that slow bootup was due to shared swap partition. So I created a separate Swap for Kali using a bootable disk and then things seemed fine.

But the issue is that hibernate (from Ubuntu) does not always work. At times, it starts up fresh like a regular bootup after shut down and I lose my system state. 
I am only interested in hibernate working from Ubuntu as I use it very often and for work. I could also re-install Kali with proper partitioning if that's what's necessary to fix this.

[image: This is how my system is currently partitioned]

Comment: The swap partition should be at least as big as your RAM size for hibernation to work. Is it? Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: Yes, it is. The swap assigned to Ubuntu is 7.89 GB whereas my RAM is 7.7 GB. Hibernate used to work fine previously before I installed Kali Linux along side Ubuntu. @Kusalananda

Comment: Just boot into Ubuntu and make sure that it's actually not using the smaller Kali swap partition as swap.

Comment: Ubuntu currently seems to be using both the swap partitions. 
sudo blkid | grep swap returns the details of both partitions. 
The larger swap (intended for Ubuntu) is listed first but how can I make it the only one used and unassign the smaller Swap partition from Ubuntu? @Kusalananda

Comment: This could well be an OS compatibilty issue with ACPI

Comment: Watch your swap usage with `free`. If your swap partition is used by Ubuntu, it may happen that there is not enough room to put your memory when you hibernate.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. I have installed Ubuntu and Kali and created two swaps - one for each but both are in use at both the OSes.